# How to invoke method "x" on failure of method "y"?

Tags: java

I want to run method x if method y fails. For example

```
public void createzoo (){

create.chimp();
if 
activateByMail.chimp() fails 
run 
activateByAdmin.chimp()

delete.chimp();

}
```

It would be good if I could use boolean to accomplish this.
I'm writing scripts in java on ubuntu

Comment: So?  Assuming that `activateByMail.chimp()` either returns a `boolean` or throws an `Exception` you should be capable of controlling the follow.  If it returns a `boolean` simply use a `if-else` statement.  If it throws an `Exception` use a `try-catch`

Comment: Its related to Java not Webdriver. post your question in Java thread.

Answer (score 2):

return boolean value from chimp() function it something goes wrong in it. and check like

```
 if(!activateByMail.chimp())
   activateByAdmin.chimp();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in these both ways,

1.
make the return type of method1 as  boolean, which if fails return false, true otherwise.

```
    boolean method1(){
    if(succeed)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
    }
```

//use it like this:

```
if(!method1()) method2();
```

2
. if you already have a return value in that method, throw some exception in method 1, and catch it in the call. and in catch block call method2.

```
    void method1(){
    if(!succeeed) throw new FailException();
    }
```

use it like this

```
    try{
    method1();
    } catch(FailException ex){
    method2();
    }
```